# How do I use Webform fields in a view?

Tags: 6, views, webforms

I use the Webform module to get user information, and I want to use some Webform fields in a view; for example, I want to show only some of the fields  (e.g. name and e-mail), and expose a filter for the user's email.

How do I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Webform vs. CCK (or D7 Field module)](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/webform#webform-vs-cck):

> Webform submissions are not nodes. This means that you can't use Views with submissions, ...

Comment: Better Views integration's being [actively worked on](http://drupal.org/node/680386) in webform.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Webform MySQL Views](http://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views).

> The Webform MySQL Views module builds flattened, read-only MySQL views of Webform
>   submission data. These views may be useful when you need to access this data
>   from an external application in an automated fashion without exporting,
>   importing, or the use of a web-based API.

Answer (score 1):

Submissions with Webform are not nodes; they are not nativly available to views. In order to do so you will need another contrib module. The best bet seems to be the data module right now. NodeOne released details on how you can get submission info in views in [this blog post](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/666); however it is not very elegant.