# webform data access through views

Tags: webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use Webform fields in a view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8971/how-do-i-use-webform-fields-in-a-view)

I have a webform with 3 fields.Name,Loan amount,and profession.I redirect the form submission to a custom url which is a view page and am passing the sid i.e. submit id as a  token.Now i want to access the 3 values in views using contextual filters.I need help on this.any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: see this link .
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8971/how-to-use-webform-field-in-views